# Jagged arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can draw arrows with `\draw [->] (0,0) -- (5,5);` with tikz. But is it also possible to create jagged arrows like

[image]

I need to use it exactly as normal arrows; from one node to another.

Comment: Please upload a drawing/photo of your desired result. How will it be used? In Math? Please also give an MWE. Standalone, article, beamer...? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question with a photo of my desired result.

Comment: Try this `\draw[->](0,0)--++(2.7,0)--++(-0.4,0.4)--++(2.7,0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a *manual* solution (it is *manual* because you must choose between horizontal and vertical lines, and between 45 or -45 angle).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  hor jagged -45/.style={to path={
      let \p{s}=(\tikztostart),  \p{e}=(\tikztotarget), \p{m}=($(\p{s})!.5!(\p{e})$),
      \p{s1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!45:(\p{s}-|\p{m})$), \p{e1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!45:(\p{e}-|\p{m})$)
      in (\p{s}) -- (\p{s1}) -- (\p{e1}) -- (\p{e})
    },
  },
  hor jagged 45/.style={to path={
      let \p{s}=(\tikztostart), \p{e}=(\tikztotarget), \p{m}=($(\p{s})!.5!(\p{e})$),
      \p{s1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!-45:(\p{s}-|\p{m})$), \p{e1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!-45:(\p{e}-|\p{m})$)
      in (\p{s}) -- (\p{s1}) -- (\p{e1}) -- (\p{e})
    },
  },
  ver jagged -45/.style={to path={
      let \p{s}=(\tikztostart), \p{e}=(\tikztotarget), \p{m}=($(\p{s})!.5!(\p{e})$),
      \p{s1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!-45:(\p{s}|-\p{m})$), \p{e1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!-45:(\p{e}|-\p{m})$)
      in (\p{s}) -- (\p{s1}) -- (\p{e1}) -- (\p{e})
    },
  },
  ver jagged 45/.style={to path={
      let \p{s}=(\tikztostart), \p{e}=(\tikztotarget), \p{m}=($(\p{s})!.5!(\p{e})$),
      \p{s1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!45:(\p{s}|-\p{m})$), \p{e1}=($(\p{m})!1.41421!45:(\p{e}|-\p{m})$)
      in (\p{s}) -- (\p{s1}) -- (\p{e1}) -- (\p{e})
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line cap=round]
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (b) at (4,1);
  \draw[line width=5pt,-latex] (a) to[hor jagged 45] (b);
  \draw[line width=3pt,red,-latex] (a) to[hor jagged -45] (b);
  \draw[line width=2pt,blue,-latex] (a) to[ver jagged 45] (b);
  \draw[line width=.5pt,green,-latex] (a) to[ver jagged -45] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `zigzag` style, that sets `to path`, as follows :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  zigzag/.style={to path={ -- ($(\tikztostart)!.55!-7:(\tikztotarget)$) -- ($(\tikztostart)!.45!7:(\tikztotarget)$) -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[-stealth,line width=1mm] (-2,2.5) to[zigzag] +(4,0);

    \foreach[evaluate={\c=\i/3.3}] \i in {0,30,...,330}
      \draw[-latex, red!\c!blue, thick] (0,0) to[zigzag] (\i:2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you always want horizontal or vertical zig-zags.  There are ways to avoid creating a bunch of new lengths, but for now this should be sufficiently confusing.

```
\documentclass[border=.1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}

\newlength{\tempx}
\newlength{\tempy}
\newlength{\absx}
\newlength{\absy}

\newcommand{\zotz}[3][->]% #1=parameters (optional), #2=from x,y, #3= to x,y
{\coordinate (zotzfrom) at (#2);
 \coordinate (zotzto) at (#3);
 \pgfextractx{\tempx}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{zotzfrom}{center}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{zotzto}{center}}};
 \pgfextracty{\tempy}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{zotzfrom}{center}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{zotzto}{center}}};
 \ifdim\tempx>0pt \absx=\tempx \else\absx=-\tempx \fi
 \ifdim\tempy>0pt \absy=\tempy \else\absy=-\tempy \fi
 \ifdim\absy>\absx
   \draw[#1] (zotzfrom) -- +(0pt,0.6\tempy) -- +(\tempx,.4\tempy) -- (zotzto);
 \else
   \draw[#1] (zotzfrom) -- +(0.6\tempx,0pt) -- +(.4\tempx,\tempy) -- (zotzto);
 \fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\zotz{0,0}{4,1}
\zotz[-latex,red]{0,1}{1,5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: zotz]